# Does TThread work differently in a Delphi 2006 console application?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, unit-testing, console-application

We have a pretty mature COM dll, which we test using DUnit. One of our recent tests creates a few threads, and tests the object from those threads. This test works fine when running the test using the gui front-end, but hangs when running as a console application. Here's a quick pseudo view of what we have in the test

```
SetupTest;
fThreadRefCount := 0; //number of active threads
Thread1 := TMyThread.Create(True);
Inc(fThreadRefCount);
Thread1.OnTerminate := HandleTerminate; //HandleOnTerminate decrements fThreadRefCount
Thread3 := TMyThread.Create(True);
Inc(fThreadRefCount);
Thread2.OnTerminate := HandleTerminate; //HandleOnTerminate decrements fThreadRefCount
Thread3 := TMyThread.Create(True);
Inc(fThreadRefCount);
Thread3.OnTerminate := HandleTerminate; //HandleOnTerminate decrements fThreadRefCount

Thread1.Resume;
Thread2.Resume;
Thread3.Resume;

while fThreadRefCount > 0 do
  Application.ProcessMessages;
```

I have tried doing nothing in the OnExecute, so I'm sure it's not the actual code I'm testing. In the console, fThreadRefCount never decrements, while if I run it as a gui app, it's fine!

As far as I can see, the OnTerminate event is just not called.

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: Revision history shows title changed; now it is clear, thanks.

Comment: Can you pare down your example to the absolute minimum that still compiles and still shows the problem? You say Synchronize is definitely not called, how did you verify that - by placing a breakpoint? If so, can you place a breakpoint in TMyThread.Execute and trace why it wasn't called?

Comment: Ok, I'll try and spend some time on it this weekend and see where I get.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to provide more data.

Note that `OnTerminate` is called via `Synchronize()`, which requires a call to `CheckSynchronize()` at some point somewhere. `Application.ProcessMessages()` normally does this, but depending on how the VCL has been initialized, it's possible that the `Synchronize()` mechanism hasn't been fully hooked together in a Console application.

In any case, this program works as expected on my machine:

```
uses Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Forms;

var
  threadCount: Integer;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
    class procedure Go;
    class procedure HandleOnTerminate(Sender: TObject);
  end;
  
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
end;

class procedure TMyThread.Go;
  function MakeThread: TThread;
  begin
    Result := TMyThread.Create(True);
    Inc(threadCount);
    Result.OnTerminate := HandleOnTerminate;
  end;
var
  t1, t2, t3: TThread;
begin
  t1 := MakeThread;
  t2 := MakeThread;
  t3 := MakeThread;
  t1.Resume;
  t2.Resume;
  t3.Resume;
  while threadCount > 0 do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

class procedure TMyThread.HandleOnTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InterlockedDecrement(threadCount);
end;

begin
  try
    TMyThread.Go;
  except
    on e: Exception do
      Writeln(e.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: It's just a simple console app. It's definitely as you describe it, the synchronize is not being called. Not sure what more information I can give.

Comment: I've had a further look at this, and when I compile the tests as a console application, checkSyncronize is not called. If I change the processmessages call to a HandleMessage, checksynchronize does get called but only if I click away from the app and back again (onidle processing)

Answer (score 5):

As Barry rightly pointed out, unless `CheckSyncronize()` is called, `Synchronize()` is not processed, and if `Synchronize()` is not processed, then the `OnTerminate` event is not fired.

What seems to be happening is that when I run my unit tests as a Console application, there are no messages on the message queue, and thus `Application.ProcessMessage()`, which is called from `Application.ProcessMessages()`, never gets to call `CheckSynchronize()`.

I've now solved the problem by changing the loop to this:

```
While fThreadRefCount > 0 do
begin
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   CheckSynchronize;
end;
```

It now works in both Console and GUI modes.

The whole `WakeupMainThread` hook seems to be setup properly. It's this hook which posts the `WM_NULL` message that triggers the `CheckSynchronize()`. It just doesn't get that far in the Console app.

**More Investigation**

So, `Synchronize()` *does* get called. `DoTerminate()` calls `Synchronize(CallOnTerminate)` but there's a line in there:

```
WaitForSingleObject(SyncProcPtr.Signal, Infinite);
```

which just waits forever.

So, while my fix above works, there's something deeper to this!

Comment: thanks so much for this post. I ahve been up all night workign on a threaded console app and couldnt get the threads to temrinate. it would hit the WaitForSingleObject line in clases.pas and just freeze. code is now working and I can get sleep. thanks again for putting this up on the site